# Pig Two Computers Game

Tags: python-3.x

I have an assignment where I need the computer to play a game of pig on his own and stop once 100 is rolled. So, I have two computer players going head to head, but the problem is that although the players could've had 100 total they keep going until `turntotal >= 20` which in return gives the other player a chance to win because there was a point where 100 could be reached. It specifically states in our assignment to look out for this problem, but I have no clue how to go about solving this issue. Also any ways to make the code cleaner would be helpful.

```
def playerOne(score):
    turntotal = 0
    scoretotal = 0
    while(scoretotal >= 0 and scoretotal <= 100):
        while(scoretotal < 100):
            roll = random.randint(1,6)
            print('Rolled a ', roll)
            if(turntotal <= 20 and roll != 1):
                turntotal = turntotal + roll
                scoretotal = scoretotal + roll
                if(turntotal >= 20):
                    break
            if(roll == 1):
                scoretotal = scoretotal - turntotal
                turntotal = 0
                print('Pigged Out!!!')
                break
        print('Turn score =', turntotal)
        turntotal = 0
        return scoretotal

def printScore():
    print(' ')
    print("Player One score is", PlayerOneScore)
    print("Player two score is", PlayerTwoScore)
    print(' ')

PlayerOneScore = 0
PlayerTwoScore = 0
flipcoin = random.randint(1,2)

if(flipcoin == 1):
    while(PlayerOneScore < 100 or PlayerTwoScore < 100):
        printScore()
        print("Player 1's turn")

        PlayerOneScore += playerOne(PlayerOneScore)
        if(PlayerOneScore >= 100):
            break

        printScore()
        print("Player 2's turn")    

        PlayerTwoScore += playerOne(PlayerTwoScore)
        if(PlayerTwoScore >= 100):
            break
else:
    while(PlayerOneScore < 100 or PlayerTwoScore < 100):
        printScore()
        print("Player 2's turn")    

        PlayerTwoScore += playerOne(PlayerTwoScore)
        if(PlayerTwoScore >= 100):
            break

        printScore()
        print("Player 1's turn")

        PlayerOneScore += playerOne(PlayerOneScore)
        if(PlayerOneScore >= 100):
            break

printScore()

if(PlayerTwoScore > PlayerOneScore):
    print("PLAYER 2 WINS")
else:
    print("PLAYER 1 WINS")
```

Comment: `or` should be `and` in `while(PlayerOneScore < 100 or PlayerTwoScore < 100):`